# iterate through FASTA entries and rename duplicates

Tags: r, bioinformatics, fasta

I have a FASTA file with a large number of entries. Although all of the DNA sequences are different, some of the FASTA names are identical. If there are multiple copies of a name I would like to append a number so that they become unique names. For example:

```
>NAME
ATTTTTGGGGGGTGTGTG
>NAME
ATTTTTTTTCGCGCGC
>NAME
AAACCCTTTGTG
```

would become:

```
>NAME_1
ATTTTTGGGGGGTGTGTG
>NAME_2
ATTTTTTTTCGCGCGC
>NAME_3
AAACCCTTTGTG
```

thanks.

update. Since I was planning on using this in R anyway I imported the fasta sequence to R and have it as a dataframe, df. I can then rename then as desired by using the following line:

```
library(plyr)
ddply(df, Name_Column, transform, Column = paste(Name_Column,seq_along(Name_Column), sep=""))
```

code inspired by this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2187448/how-do-i-use-plyr-to-number-rows)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Biostrings](http://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/Biostrings.html) package of [Bioconductor](http://bioconductor.org) has

```
library(Biostrings)
fa = read.DNAStringSet(...)
```

Then

```
names(fa) = make.unique(names(fa))
write.XStringSet(fa, ...)
```

or other useful manipulations.

Comment: thanks Martin. I used Biostrings for importing my FASTA but didn't realize they have the make.unique() function. That is very useful. As you can see I used a dataframe approach but I had to get from the Biostring container to a dataframe which took a few extra steps. Thank you

Comment: @zach `make.unique` is actually in base R; we're just using it here.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following AWK command:

```
$ echo -e ">A\nNNNN\n>A\nNNNNNNN" |\
awk '/^>/ { printf("%s_%s\n",$0,i++);next;} { print $0;}'

>A_0
NNNN
>A_1
NNNNNNN
```

See also Biostar: http://biostar.stackexchange.com

Comment: +1 - If I understand this correctly, it's sufficient to make every sequence name unique -- by appending a unique index to *all* sequence names, whether they were duplicates or not. Adding indexes *only* to duplicates would be feasible, but a little more complex.

Comment: thanks Pierre. That awk script will indeed add a unique ID to each FASTA record. ideally, as suggested by @andythomas-cramer the script would only add it to duplicates and the count would reset for each duplicate pairs.

Comment: @zach, are the duplicates adjacent to each other in the file, or spread out? Also, is each sequence known to be listed on exactly one line in addition to the description line?

Comment: @andythomas-cramer the duplicates are not necessarily adjacent to one another. the sequences are all exactly one line and are the same length. Ultimately I would like to use this data in R so I am thinking of importing the fasta file as a datatable, sorting the table, and then spliting/renumbering them. Command line would be easier and better although my initial inclination was to write each entry to a new file and then do a search to see if the name already exists.

Comment: @zach - If you sort the sequences by name, you can do this in a single pass, looking ahead to the next sequence before writing the current. Alternatively, you could keep a mapping from names to counts as you read through the FASTA file in the original order, with one pass for (A, A1, A2...) and two passes for (A1,A2,A3).